# How to prove this relation between the laplacian of the logarithm and the dirac delta function?

Tags: analysis, dirac-delta, laplacian

Why is this true in two dimensions?
$$\nabla^2\bigg(\ln(r)\bigg)=2\pi\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{r}),$$
where $\delta^{(2)}$ denotes the two-dimensional $\delta$-function and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in Cartesian coordinates.

I understand that both function will look the same. But I do not know how to prove this rigorously.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Let  $\phi \in C^\infty_{c}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. You need to show
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \log|x| \Delta \varphi(x)\ dx = 2\pi \varphi(0).
\end{align}

This can be done by splitting the left-hand side into
\begin{align}
\int_{B(0, \epsilon)} \log|x| \Delta \varphi(x)\ dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}^2\backslash B(0, \epsilon)} \log |x| \Delta \varphi(x)\ dx = I_1+I_2.
\end{align}
For $I_2$, use integration by parts to put the Laplacian on to $\log |x|$ (don't forget the boundary term).  For $I_1$, show it vanishes as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.  Remember the boundary term? Show that converges to the desired quantity as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to use the Answer panel, but I am not allowed to comment. Please, see the answer to this related question for more details on the calculations:

[Distributional Laplacian of logarithm and the Dirac delta distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556289/distributional-laplacian-of-logarithm-and-the-dirac-delta-distribution?rq=1)