# Electrostatic Potential and Compactly Supported Functions

Tags: laplacian

I found the following expression in IMRN International Mathematics Research Notices 2005, No. 34, page# 2064.

Let $\phi$ be a $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ then $$\int_{\mathbb{C}}\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|z|\Delta\phi(z)dxdy = \phi(0).$$ Here $\Delta \phi$ is the Laplacian of $\phi$.

I am not entirely sure how to get this integral. Any hint or explanation will be a great help.

Comment: See [How to prove this relation between the laplacian of the logarithm and the dirac delta function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1932460/568204) and the various linked answers. It's pretty much the same calculation as what's already written there, but another way of saying it is to consider for each $\epsilon>0$, the integral $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(|z|+\epsilon^2)\Delta \phi(z)\,dx\,dy$. We can now shift the Laplacian over to the $\log$ term (no boundary terms arise now), and then eventually let $\epsilon\to 0^+$ (all justified due to dominated convergence theorem).

Comment: I think this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

So, it essentially says that the $\textit{distribution}~$ Laplacian of $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2\pi}\log\left( \frac{1}{|z|}\right)$ with respect to $z$ is the point mass at $0$. For more details, one can see Theodore W. Gamelin's book on "Complex Analysis, Page # 393-394"[1]. It's a beautiful application of Green's second identity.

.
[1]: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387950938

Comment: To my good fortune Prof. Rudnick the author of IMRN International Mathematics Research Notices 2005, No. 34, also provides one reference: page 95 of G. B. Folland's book "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations". Thanks to @peek-o-boo and Prof. Rudnick.