# Examples of distributions induced by principal value integrals

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, singular-integrals

I am looking for a source that provides as many examples as possible of distributions induced by principal value integrals similar to [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162931/principal-value-as-distribution-written-as-integral-over-singularity?rq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824486/derivative-of-principal-value-distribution-1-x-is-equal-to-finite-part-distrib#), and [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556289/distributional-laplacian-of-logarithm-and-the-dirac-delta-distribution). Any suggestions? If not, please let me know of any examples you know with the final value and I'll work it out

Comment: Those three are closely related: $\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} = (\ln|x|)'$ and $\operatorname{fp}\frac{1}{x^2} = - (\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x})'.$ You can of course continue taking derivatives.

Comment: If $f\in C^\infty$ has a zero of degree 1 at $a$ then $\frac{1}{f}$ is a distribution of pv-type in a neighborhood of $a$. One such example is $f=\sin.$

Comment: Thanks. You're right. But these examples are overused. I'm looking for something that I haven't seen yet.

Comment: Perhaps a one-sided like the derivative of $H(x) \ln(x)$? Also, there are some examples of finite part distributions in the [Lecture Notes by Hasse Carlsson](http://www.math.chalmers.se/%7Ehasse/distributioner_eng.pdf).

Comment: I think that $\frac{1}{x}\ln|x|$ can be interpreted as a distribution of pv-type.